# Better understanding of Drupal behaviors

Tags: 7, javascript

I read about Drupal behaviors today, and I tried writing the following code.

```
(function ($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('#mymodule_id', context).change(function () {
        alert('Handler for .change() called.');
      });
    }
  };

}(jQuery));
```

- Is `Drupal.behaviors.mymodule` the namespace?
- What are the context and settings parameters passed to the Drupal behavior?
- Is this the equivalent of `document.ready()`?
- Can I attach any number of functions?
- Can I define JavaScript functions which will be called somewhere?

Comment: This blog post from Lullabot does a great job of explaining the concepts around JS behaviors: https://www.lullabot.com/articles/understanding-javascript-behaviors-in-drupal

Comment: Good article here about behaviors for all the versions (D6, D7 & D8): https://www.benmarshall.me/drupal-behaviors/

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In short, the advantage of Behaviors over `document.ready()` is that they are automatically re-applied to any content loaded through AJAX. `mymodule` is your namespace, which needs to be unique. `context` is the part of the page for which this applies, for example a part of a form that has been updated with AJAX. You can attach multiple behaviors, but I think you need to use a unique name (mymodule) for each of those.

Have a look at the following resources for more information:

- [Drupal behaviors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941426/drupal-behaviours)
- [Drupal Javascript API](http://drupal.org/node/304258)
- [Changes in the Drupal JS API for D7](http://drupal.org/node/756722)

Answer (score 4):

In easy words, `Drupal.behaviors` is a better way to implement `jQuery.ready`

Unlike `jQuery.ready` which only runs once when the DOM is ready, `Drupal.behaviors` can be ran multiple times during page execution.

For example, in views infinite scroll, more elements will be loaded when user clicks load more button, hence , DOM will change after initial load.

What if we want to add classes to the newly added elements? Here Drupal Behaviors come handy.

> The behaviors will be executed on every request including AJAX
>   requests.

Drupal will call attached behaviors when the DOM is loaded and also when it is changed by Ajax, passing in two arguments

**context** and **settings**

The first time Drupal.attachBehaviors() is called, the **context** variable contains the document object representing the DOM, but for the rest of the calls context will hold the affected piece of HTML.

**settings** contains information passed on to JavaScript via PHP, it is similar to accessing it via Drupal.settings.

Furthermore, modules may call Drupal.attachBehaviors() as well.