# Views slideshow countinuous rotation

Tags: 7, views

I have some contents (organisms : a content type) to slide continuously... I already installed [views slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) 7.x-3.0 for another slider which has normal behavior.

Is it possible that I get my organisms rotate continuously like HTML marquee effect ?

with [views slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) or other modules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've searched on [drupal](http://drupal.org), and I've created a [patch](http://drupal.org/node/1236004#comment-7110646) for [views_slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) to make it possible.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, Views Slideshow doesn't really make things easier (unless maybe if you don't want to write a single line of code).

I prefer to create a normal view (displaying fields or a rendered entity, whatever you like) and use [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) to turn the views rows into slides. You just need to:

1. download the jQuery Cycle plugin to your theme's javascript directory
2. add a '[Drupal behavior](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11756/better-understanding-of-behaviours-of-drupal-7)' to a custom javascript file which initiates the jQuery Cycle (see the example code on the jQuery Cycle site)
3. make sure both javascript files are loaded by adding them to your theme's .info file

jQuery Cycle can definitely rotate continuously, just look at the demo's on its homepage.

Comment: To the downvoter: please let me know what's wrong with this answer, so I can improve it.