# How can I use Javascript (Google Analytics) in my "Rewrite Results" in Views?

Tags: views, javascript, input-formats

I'm trying to track downloads as events in Google Analytics for file fields.  The links are displayed in Views using "Rewrite results."

I tried the following:

```
<a onclick="var that=this;_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Download','Windows',this.href]);setTimeout(function(){location.href=that.href;},400);return false;" href=[field_windows]>Windows</a>
```

But the **onclick** part gets stripped out by Views.  I know the Full HTML filter does this by default, but how do I get around it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Views will indeed strip out onclick attributes.
You can work with data attributes and use an external JS file to add the onclicks.
Example for Views rewrite:

```
<a href="#mylink" data-event-type="Download" data-event-xxxx="Windows">[myfield]</a>
```

External Javascript (jQuery example):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 if(jQuery("a[data-event-type]"){
   jQuery("a[data-event-type]").click(function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent',jQuery(this).attr('data-event-type'),...........);
   });
 }
});
```

Comment: Did you test this?  Views also apparently strips out "data-event-type" and "data-event-xxxx"...

Comment: I did, I'm using it this way all the time.

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten to clear the caches, sorry.  Thanks, this did the trick for me.

Comment: Please, modify answer to implement Drupal.behaviors, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/12026/487 and http://blog.amazeelabs.com/en/drupal-behaviors-quick-how

Answer (score 4):

It would probably be better to add a class to the element and then attach the click event via a JS behavior anyway.

I don't think this field uses text formats at all, but must apply some default level of filtering e.g. `filter_xss()`.

**Edit:** Here's an example that attaches the tracking and download using a class and the link text for the event name.

```
<a class="download-link" href="[field_windows]">Windows</a>
```

Add this to your theme or module JS:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.triggerDownload = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.download-link').once('trigger-download').click(function (e) {
          var href = this.href;
          _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Download', $(this).text(), href]);
          setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.href = href;
          }, 400);
          e.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, but I'm not very familiar with JS.  How would I attach the click event via a JS behavior?

Comment: Added an example. Just seen Kevin's solution. Data attributes are definitely another option. I would strongly recommend using Drupal behaviors rather than attaching to document ready though.

Comment: Why should I use Drupal behaviors instead of document ready?

Comment: @PatrickKenny see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/12026/487

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [GA Push module](https://drupal.org/project/ga_push).

This module allows you to send events to GA when certain JS events happens. You can define this interactions using its GUI.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldnt be stripping the onclick if you have Full HTML selected. Are you using Ck Editor 4.1 +?

Theres a known issue where tags are being stripped if you dont edit the .js file directly, or add `config.allowedContent = true;` into the Advanced Content Filter settings.

From the CKeditor project page:

> Note for CKEditor 4.1+ users
>
> If you are using CKEditor 4.1+, you should adjust Advanced Content
>   Filter settings. If you have any trouble implementing this feature,
>   you can turn it off by setting:
>
> config.allowedContent = true;
>
> in the Custom JavaScript configuration field of the Advanced Options
>   setion for your CKEditor profiles.

Comment: I'm not using CKEditor; I'm using the standard Views UI, which allows Full HTML by default (that's my understanding, anyway).