# JS not run with custom module

Tags: javascript

I have created custom module with drupal 8 after successfully installation on my module run properly with java script but after its not working till now , i have done multiple changes in my module controller file but module has not run .

my controller file code is here :

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Controller for generating JSON response.
 */

namespace Drupal\ipew\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;


/**
 * Controller for d3 ipew.
 */
class ipewController extends ControllerBase {
  /**
   * Display the markup.
   *
   * @return array
   */

   public function content() {

      return [
      '#title' => 'Hello World',
      '#markup' => 'Welcome to this World',
    ];
   }

}
```

*.info.yml file code is here :

```
name: ipew
type: module
description: Attack map
core: 8.x
package: Custom
```

*.liabraries.yml code is here :

```
ipew:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/d3.v3.min.js: {}
    js/ipew.js: {}
    js/d3.geo.projection.v0.min.js: {}
    js/topojson.v1.min.js: {}
    js/datamaps.world.min.js: {}
    js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js: {}
    js/jquery.simplemodal-1.4.4.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupalSettings
```

*.routing.yml is here :

```
ipew.list:
  path: '/ipew'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\ipew\Controller\ipewController::content'
    _title_callback: '\Drupal\ipew\Controller\ipewController::getTitle'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

*.html.twig file is here :

```
{# ipew/templates/ipew.html.twig #}
<p>IPEW</p>
 
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
```

This module only show hello world in output .

Answer (score 3):

You need to attach your library:

```
return [
  '#title' => 'Hello World',
  '#markup' => 'Welcome to this World',
  '#attached' => [
    // Add the ipew library from the ipew module
    // in the format [MODULE]/[LIBRARY].
    'library' => 'ipew/ipew',
  ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

As japan told you, you need to attach the library.

You need also to configure your `ipew.libraries.yml`

```
lorem_ipsum:
  version: 1
  js:
    js/your-file.min.js: {minified: true}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

And in your js file :

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
    Drupal.behaviors.ipew = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
             // your js code

        }
    };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

The advantage of Behaviors over document.ready() is that they are automatically re-applied to any content loaded through AJAX :
[Better understanding of Drupal behaviors](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11756/better-understanding-of-drupal-behaviors#answer-12026)