# Jquery to move field above the table - changes during page refresh

Tags: views, javascript, ajax, 9

I have the below jquery code to move a multiselect field and a button above the table.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#views-form-resources-block-1 .form-item-ka-types').insertBefore($('#views-form-myblock-block-1 table'));
  $('#views-form-resources-block-1 #edit-actions--2').insertAfter($('#views-form-myblock-block-1 .form-item-ka-types'));
});
```

In this code I am moving the ka-types field above myblock view. Pictorial representation as below:

[image]

This code works fine when I load the page at first. But when I refresh the page, the multiselect comes down and shows messed up. again when I refresh the page it works fine. not sure what the problem is. Any help on how this can be fixed?

Comment: The Javascript is not written in a way that Drupal will attach it when the dom changes, so when a form rebuilds, this will be lost. It's probably easier to override this Views template to move a filter vs force it with jquery.

Comment: Otherwise review the Drupal docs on Drupal Behaviors.

Comment: I would also recommend doing this with yourjavas view's template. JavaScript changes like this will cause the page contents to shift which is not a nice UX. This could even negatively affect your SEO as a page's [Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS)](https://web.dev/cls/) score is a factor.

Comment: Could you precise please, what the first refreshing means? A form submit? So maybe the DOM looks a little different after submitting.

Comment: You can also check if web tools console shows any JS error, so your JS is never executed after submitting the form (first refresh)

Comment: I am able to achieve this using Drupal Behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

The below is my solution for this:

```
(function($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.searchResults = {
    attach: function() {
      $('#views-form-resources-block-1 .form-item-ka-types')
        .insertBefore($('#views-form-myblock-block-1 table'));
      $('#views-form-resources-block-1 #edit-actions--2')
        .insertAfter($('#views-form-myblock-block-1 .form-item-ka-types'));
    }
  };
}(jQuery, Drupal));
```

@Kevin is correct. When the form rebuilds the DOM changes are lost. [Better understanding of Drupal behaviors](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11756/better-understanding-of-drupal-behaviors) link has great explanation and examples of Drupal Behavior.