# How will I highlight active item in glossary view?

Tags: views, 9

I have created a glossary view which shows alphabetical navigation to filter the list.

But I can't find a way to highlight the active link - would like for "G" to be highlighted if I am clicking the "G".

I have this [tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/558602) for this but it works only when ajax is disabled. But I am using ajax for this glossary view.

Below is the code which isn't working

```
$(".view-display-id-attachment_1 span a").each(function(){
     if($(this).attr("href") == location.pathname) {
       $(this).addClass('my-class');
     }
});
```

I want something like this

[image]

When **C** will be clicked it will be highlighted this way

How will I achieve this in view glossary when **ajax is enabled**?

Thanks in advance.

Please check the issue I am facing currently. [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2QSa.jpg)

Comment: Is that code inside of an attach property as shown in the JavaScript API docs? https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview If it is not, it should be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better understanding of Drupal behaviors](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11756/better-understanding-of-drupal-behaviors)

Comment: @cilefen that code is working if the glossary is not ajax enabled. But my glossary view is Ajax enabled. Though as per your suggestion I added this code `Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {attach: function (context, settings) {$('#.view-display-id-attachment_1 span a', context).change(function () {alert('hi');});}};`. But its not working.

Comment: @cilefen I have edited my question and added a link to show the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many research I understood that unfortunately glossary view doesn't add `is-active` class if AJAX enabled in the view.

So I had to use a contrib module for that. It provides a simple A-Z filter as radio button/checkbox.

https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_view_filters